# Access to image at s3 image from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Using jquery-cropper and creating using external image from s3 but it gives an error `Access to image at s3 image from origin has been blocked by CORS policy`

JS code

```
img = new Image
img.crossOrigin = '*'
img.id = 'edit-container-canvas'
img.class = 'cropper-hidden'
img.src = 'http://memoryguard.s3.amazonaws.com/family_tributes/3796/15c15f72-823e-46b3-b178-2bb8d42c5386.jpg'
```

AWS Bucket CORS Settings

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
```

I tried a lot of solutions but none of them working :(

Comment: can you try https:// img_link ? or does that not work also?

Comment: Yes I tried that also :) :)

Comment: @Rustyjim same issue :)